# C# Setting a value in a single element of a multi-level array is setting the value in every element

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have defined an array inside an array with

`var frames = Enumerable.Repeat(new[] { -1, 0, 0, 0 }, 10).ToArray();`

This gives me `frames` as `int[10][]` and `frames[0]` as `int[4]` with the values -1, 0, 0, and 0.  The same values, of course, are in `frames[1]` thru `frames[9]`.

I then make this assignment:

`frames[vara][varb] = value;`

where vara and varb are both 0 and value is 5.

Now, every element of `frames`, from `frames[0]` through `frames[9]` has the value 5 at `frames[n][0]`, even though I explicitly said, assign this value to `frames[0][0]`.

Why is every value in frames getting set?

Comment: Think about how `Enumerable.Repeat` would be implemented. Given `x`, it will create a sequence `x, x, x, x, ..., x`. Since `x` is essentially a reference to the array, all entries point to the same array,

Comment: I believe this is because `new[] { -1, 0, 0, 0 }` is an object added `n` times, but is still the same object. So if you update it at one place, it will be updated everywhere.

You should get the same result if you update `frames[1][0]`

You will need to create a new object foreach add.

Comment: @Marius - that is it.  I replaced the initialization of frames with `var frames = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(r => new[] { -1, 0, 0, 0 }).ToArray();` and it worked.